# docker airflow configuration issues (puckel/docker)

Tags: python, docker, airflow

After pulling the docker image [from here](https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow) I realised after attaching a shell that the tutorial files are not in the dag folder specified in airflow.cg (dags_folder = /usr/local/airflow/dags, the folder dags does not exist).
The tutorial file is actually found here instead:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/example_dags/tutorial.py

In addition, running a airflow list_dag raises warnings about kubernetes not bieng installed and I am missing the permissions to run apt-get for applications like vim to edit py files, or even run ps to view processes.

As I am new to docker and airflow, is there anything I need to change in the dockerfile when building?

Note: I am using Docker for windows to build the linux image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The warnings about Kubernetes come from the fact that the `airflow[kubernetes]` module is not installed by default by Puckel's Dockerfile, but it's not something to worry about unless you want to use Airflow's KubernetesPodOperator.

It's also normal that you don't have permission to edit python modules when you go inside the container, because there you are logged as user `airflow` and not as root and that user only has write access to the $AIRFLOW_HOME directory. In general editing files from inside the container is hackish and you should try to avoid that.

If I guess correctly, what you want to do is to have your own dags been loaded from airflow-docker. If that's the case, you can run something like the following:

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -v <local_path_to_your_dags>:/usr/local/airflow/dags  puckel/docker-airflow webserver
```

Here you're mounting a local folder from your machine to the HOME/dags folder in the container, which is the one used to load dags.